# Named range in chart copying

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-charts

I'm having the same issue copying a chart in an Excel sheet involving named ranges in formulas to another one (see post [Copy chart and named range (excel 2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921698/copy-chart-and-named-range-excel-2010/32748004)). Although the named range is copied in name manager, the named range copies as a reference, ie $A$1, vs xrange. (I'm using Excel 2007).

Can anyone make any suggestions to make this work?